# Sum Up for each element of Collection.find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to sum up a specific column of my DataPoints Collection which fits to a specific Query.

```
getClicksTotalCampaign: function () {
    var docs = DataPoints.find({campaign: this._id, influencer: Meteor.userId()});
            var clicks = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i< docs.length; i++) {
                clicks += parseInt(docs[i].clicks);
            }
            return clicks;
    },
```

I am wrong with the return of DataPoints.find beeing an Array of Objects? The length of it is always null, when i do the query on mongo i get entrys back.
@edit Here the Data Schema:

```
Schemas.DataPoints = new SimpleSchema({

    influencer: {
        type: String,
        label: "Influencer ID"
    },
    advertiser: {
        type: String,
        label: "Advertiser ID"
    },
    campaign: {
        type: String,
        label: "Campaign ID"
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Amount"
    }    
});
```

Comment: what does the `docs ` hold ?

Comment: the return from the query DataPoints.find(....)

Comment: can you give the mongo doc(structure)??

Comment: i added the schema :)

Comment: I take it the `clicks` field is an array but you don't declare it in your schema, right?

Comment: sorry this was just an mistake in the question, i use "amount" not clicks. But all my tests i made with the field "amount". Which is not an array just a  number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you can use the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline operator to filter the collection on the campaign and influencer. The **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step then groups all the input documents from the filter and applies the accumulator expression **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** to the group to get the total documents count.

Your pipeline would look like this:

```
var DataPoints = new Mongo.Collection('datapoints');
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "campaign": this._id, 
            "influencer": Meteor.userId()
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {"$sum": "$amount"}
        }
    }
];
var result = DataPoints.aggregate(pipeline).fetch();
var count = result[0].count;
```

You can add the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation in Meteor:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Since this package exposes **`.aggregate`** method on Mongo.Collection instances, you can then call the method to get the result array with the document that has the count field. For example

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var DataPoints = new Mongo.Collection('datapoints');
    Meteor.methods({
        getClicksTotalCampaign: function () {
            var pipeline = [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "campaign": this._id, 
                        "influencer": Meteor.userId()
                    }
                },                  
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": null,
                        "count": {"$sum": "$amount"}
                    }
                }
            ];
            var result = DataPoints.aggregate(pipeline);
            return result[0].count;
        }
    }); 
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    setInterval(function () {
        Meteor.call('getClicksTotalCampaign', updateCounter);
    }, 1000 * 10);

    function updateCounter(err, count) {
        console.log("this is the new count: ", count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do i sum up the attribute "clicks" in your solution?

Comment: @MarioDeubler I've revised the answer to include another workaround as I had not considered you want the count off the clicks array in your document, the aggregation framework handles this much better.

Comment: hey chridam thanks for your answer, your solutions sounds like "the" solution but sadly i still get "Exception while invoking method 'getClicksTotalCampaign' TypeError: Object  has no method 'fetch'" (i installed the meteorhacks:aggregate package)

Comment: @MarioDeubler Actually there is no need to call the `fetch()` method as the aggregate method itself returns the result array. You can check the tests for it [**here**](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/test.js).

Comment: Now i use:  `var result = DataPoints.aggregate(pipeline);
        return result[0].count;                TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`

Comment: @MarioDeubler I initially thought there was a `clicks` field in your schema which was an array, so that's why it doesn't work. I've updated the pipeline which should give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var docs = DataPoints.find({campaign: this._id, influencer: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
```

Comment: I tried it also, .find returns the collection but find(....).fetch() returns nothing (an empty array of objects)....

Comment: i replace this with the question code and it works fine. clicks also giving the total of the all matched document. i think some think wrong with your query `DataPoints.find({campaign: this._id, influencer: Meteor.userId()})`...check **this._id** or **Meteor.userId()** is in correct format match with mongo doc... @chridam answer also gives the advance solution of your problem.